# "ValueError: Could not find the input entity for PeerChannel" with Bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telethon

For the life of me, I can't figure out this one out.
I have created a new Telegram Bot and created a new channel, in which I added my bot as an Admin.

After reading 100 times the [docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/entities.html), I tried to have the entity "seen" somehow but :

- get_dialogs() is not allowed for bots
- client.get_entity('') is not allowed for bots

Not sure what else to do…

I do have published some messages in the channel.

My code looks something like :

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

telethon_client = TelegramClient(
    api_id=int(config['TELETHON_API_ID']),
    api_hash=config['TELETHON_API_HASH'],
    session=config['TELETHON_SESSION']
).start(bot_token=config['TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN'])

with telethon_client:
   telethon_client.loop.run_until_complete(__async_get_users(chat_id))

async def __async_get_users(chat_id):
    channel = await telethon_client.get_entity(chat_id) # -100xxxxx
    tg_users = await telethon_client.get_participants(channel)
```

Any help, lead, or idea appreciated !

Comment: When the bot is in the channel, after it receives a new message update (you may need to make it admin or disable privacy mode in [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather)), then the library should "see" the channel.

Comment: Hi @Lonami, Thanks a lot for the tip. I tried to turn Group Privacy off (it was already an admin) and to re-send messages in the channel but I still get the same error :/ 
Any other idea?

Comment: The only way bots can get a channel access hash is through updates. Telegram should be sending the entities, and the library should be adding them to cache. It is strange that it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, not sure what lead to the resolution of this issue but I did :

- disable group privacy mode in @BotFather as @Lonami advised
- Sent other messages in the group
- Removed and re-added the bot to the group

I still had the issue, but after **clearing the session**, it now works OK!

Thanks @Lonami for the help!